# pass php variable through name in javascript appended to html

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this one line of code in my js function, I am trying to pass the id from the databse table through the name attribute.

However it is breaking my javascript and not correctly passing.

```
$("#a"+$selected.val()).append('<input type="hidden" name="'<?php echo json_encode($data['id']); ?>'" value="'+$selected.text()+'">');
```

Full function to get a better view of issue:

```
$(function() {
$("#event").hide();
$("#events").hide();
$("#myselect select").change(function() {
var $selected = $('#myselect select option:selected');
if (!$selected.hasClass('added')) {
  $('<li />', {
    'data-value': $selected.val(),
    id:'a'+$selected.val(),
    text: $selected.text()
  }).appendTo('#events');
  $selected.addClass('added');
  $("#a"+$selected.val()).append('<input type="hidden" name="'<?php echo json_encode($data['id']); ?>'" value="'+$selected.text()+'">');
}

$("#event").show();
$("#events").show();


});
});
```

Updated:

```
console.log('<?php echo $data['id']; ?>');
```

outputs:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8809/locations". jquery.js:3492(anonymous function) jquery.js:3492fire jquery.js:3048self.fireWith jquery.js:3160jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:433completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you dont want to `json_encode` it as the variable `$data['id']` will not be an array and just a string or number. Also you are using both single and double quotes to wrap the value where just one will do the task. So do

```
name="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"
```

instead of

```
name="'<?php echo json_encode($data['id']); ?>'"
```

Comment: doing that breaks the entire js function.

Comment: Would you mind putting the latest code you tried on the question. also if it broke the code, then put the error you got in console.

Comment: I think your answer is right, I might not even be getting the value. I need to do some heavy debugging then I will be back to post.

Comment: @Bobby : brother. you dont need to do toomuch debuging. just open the source code via your browser and check if the php code properly rendered on the html. If not working, update that in question. Also your console will have hint to the error put that also.